# it is possible to duplicate a complete google cloud project with minimal manual interaction?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

It is possible to duplicate a complete google cloud project with minimal manual interaction?
The purpose of this duplication is to create a white label.
In case there is no "easy" way, can you tell me what tools I can use to duplicate my existing project?

Comment: AFAIK there are tools or "easy way" to duplicate an existing GCP project. The best method is to start with a tool like Terraform to create resources. Then you can easily duplicate everything with a single command.

Comment: John Hanley thanks for your reply. I have a project in GCP, it is very large and I need to clone or create a replica of it. I used terraformer (it is a tool that allows terraform reverse engineering) with all the resources, but when I try to create my replica project with those generated files, I get errors in the configuration of features such as networks.
I think the correct thing to do is to generate only one set of resources instead of all,
Do you know what resources I should generate with terraformer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) to reverse engineering your infrastructure. You can generate TF file that you will be able to use with terraform in the other project.

However, it's only the infrastructure. Your VM configuration, your app contents, your data (file and database) content aren't duplicated! No magic tools for this.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have a project in GCP, it is very large and I need to clone or create a replica of it. I used terraformer (it is a tool that allows terraform reverse engineering) with all the resources, but when I try to create my replica project with those generated files, I get errors in the configuration of features such as networks. I think the correct thing to do is to generate only one set of resources instead of all, Do you know what resources I should generate with terraformer?

Comment: What's the problem with the network?  VPC or IP range are already used? Do you have shared resources (like Public IP, public DNS, VPN or peering connectivity)?

Comment: a Good practice when answering is to add the relevant content from a link in the answer itself to assure the answer will remain seful even if the link breaks